# Haystack Elasticsearch shows no results Django

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

Hello I am trying to implement a Search into my (local)Site and used Haystack for it. For the Backend i choose Whoosh, which worked a bit (I got some results but not as many as i wanted) so I tried to switch to Elasticsearch instead because there is way more support and active users. I got Elasticsearch running on Port 9200 (Version 5.4.0).

`./manage.py rebuild_index` is working when I run `./manage.py haystack_info` I get

```
Number of handled 3 index(es).
  - Model: Tag by Index: <my_profile.search_indexes.TagIndex object at 0x10ff51ae0>
  - Model: UserProfile by Index: <my_profile.search_indexes.UserIndex object at 0x10ff51c18>
  - Model: Post by Index: <my_profile.search_indexes.PostIndex object at 0x10ff51db8>
```

The Problem is Haystack is not finding any Results, no matter what I search for. It has to be something with Elasticsearch because I got results with Whoosh before. I have a `search_indexes.py` file and the `Post_text.txt` in the right folder.

When I run $ curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/PostIndex/_mapping?pretty=1' in the Terminal he shows me an Error that the Index is not found. This appears to be a Problem with Version 5.x of Elasticsearch and it is [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40596044/no-results-found-on-django-haystack-elasticsearch) to use Version 2.x or 1.x.

Does anybody know what I could do to get results? Should I downgrade to 2.4 and if yes do I need to reinstall everything or is there a shortcut because getting it to run one time wasn't a fun time.

I hope somebody can help me.